# How to create an actionscript Object in Haxe

Tags: object, video, actionscript, haxe

I am creating an actionscript video player in Haxe and to avoid the asyncError I am trying to create a custom Object.  How do I do this is Haxe?

The client property specifies the object on which callback methods are invoked. The default object is the NetStream object being created. If you set the client property to another object, callback methods will be invoked on that other object.

Here is my code.

```
public function new() 
{
    super();
    trace("video");
    //initialize net stream
    nc = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(null);
    ns = new NetStream(nc);
    buffer_time = 2;
    ns.bufferTime = buffer_time;

    //Add video to stage
    myVideo = new flash.media.Video(640, 360);
    addChild(myVideo);

    //Add callback method for listeing on NetStream meta data
    client = new Dynamic();
    ns.client = client;
    client.onMetaData = metaDataHandler;


}

public function playVideo(url:String)
{
    urlName = new String(url);
    myVideo.attachNetStream(ns);
    ns.play(urlName);
    ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netstat);
}

function netstat(stats:NetStatusEvent)
{
    trace(stats.info.code);
}

function metaDataHandler(infoObject:Dynamic) 
{
    myVideo.width = infoObject.width;
    myVideo.height = infoObject.height;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using { } ?
as in client = {};

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do:

`client : Dynamic = {};`

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to have an example of playing an .flv in haxe?

Comment: I ended up using ns.client = this;  I get no errors now, but still can't seem to play a video.  Any tutorials out there?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the client object; it isn't necessary for playing FLVs or for handling async errors. For that, just add a listener to the **NetStream** for `AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR`.

I suggest you add a listener to the **NetConnection** and the **NetStream** for `NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS`, and then trace out the `event.info.code` value within the listener.

You should first see the string "NetConnection.Connect.Success" coming from the **NetConnection**; when you play your video through the **NetStream**, you should see "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound" if there's a problem loading the FLV. Otherwise you should see "NetStream.Play.Start".

Unless you're progressively streaming your FLV, you may not see any video playing until the file has finished loading. If the movie file is long, this may explain why your program is running without errors but isn't playing the movie. There are small test FLV files available online that you might wish to use while you track the problem down.

(ActionScript's FLV playback API is bizarre and haXe's documentation is rudimentary, so you're rightfully frustrated.)

Answer (score 0):

This maybe useful... http://code.google.com/p/zpartan/source/browse/zpartan/media/
You can see it being used
http://code.google.com/p/jigsawx/